# Inclined pyramid pattern

Tags: javascript

I want to create a pyramid-pattern (on the side).
I've gotten the first part, but I need help to count the last part down.
So far I've got this:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){

    if ( i <= 10){

        for ( var j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
            out.innerHTML += "*";
        }

    } else if (i > 10){

        for (var j = 9; j > 0; j--){
            out.innerHTML += "*";
        }
    }

    out.innerHTML += "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: Hey @Karen did you see my answer? Did it help you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but yes I did. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop from `19-i` to `0`, and while `i` increments further the value of `19-i` gets smaller and smaller:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out");

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){

    if ( i <= 10){

        for ( var j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
            out.innerHTML += "*";
        }

    } else if (i > 10){
        for ( var j = 19-i; j >= 0; j--){ // <-- run loop so that number of iterations gets lower and lower
            out.innerHTML += "*";
        }
    }

    out.innerHTML += "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to draw [`Pyramid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)) shape based on the given steps`/`count:

```js
var steps = 5, outputStr = "", isTriangle = false;
var newLine = "<br />"; // "\n" for String, <br /> for element break line.
for (var i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {
    // Forward
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        outputStr += i;
    }
    outputStr += newLine;
    if (i == steps && !isTriangle) {
        // Backward - After completing Forward
        var k = i - 1;
        while (k > 0) {
            for (var j = k; j > 0; j--) {
                outputStr += k;
            }
            k--;
            outputStr += newLine;
        }
    }
}
var out = document.getElementById("out");
out.innerHTML = outputStr;
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

for java see: [Draw Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518616/5081877)